# What happens if a Tech Lab or a Reactor get destroyed while producing units?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

Suppose I have a building (e.g. Barracks) with a

- Tech Lab
- Reactor

What will happen if the addon gets destroyed while the building is producing units?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the units and the addon the following will happen:

Barracks with Tech Lab producing Marauder and following queue: [Marine, Marauder, Marine, Marauder]

- Current Marauder is still produced without delay
- Queue: [Marine, Marine]

Barracks with Reactor producing 2 Marines and 8 Marines in queue.

- Only 1 Marine is build without delay
- Production of other Marine is stopped and resumed as soon as first Marine finishes (see example)
- Queue: 4 Marines

Example

2 Marines are produced in Barracks with Reactor. Reactor gets destroyed after 20 seconds (Marines require 25 seconds). After 5 seconds the first Marine finishes (25 seconds). 5 seconds later (30 seconds) the seconds Marine is done. Thus you need 30 seconds instead of 25 to produce 2 Marines.

Comment: Not quite. The second marine's training time when a reactor is destroyed isn't canceled, it just halts. So if you destroy a reactor with two Marines both 20/25 done, the first will pop after 5 seconds and the next after 10 seconds. Pretty sure this is what I've seen happen, anyway.

Comment: I will test this later.

Comment: @Decency: You are right. I changed the answer accordingly.